# elasticsearch rails - illegal latitude value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, geospatial

When trying to search from latitude dynamically from records in my index I've been getting an illegal latitude value. When looking at my index I can't see any invalid latitude and longitude values, so I'm guessing it's an error in my code.

Exact error;

```
{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194] for [geo_distance]","index":"addresses","line":1,"col":172}}]},"status":400}
```

Model code for search;

```
def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
            query:{
                multi_match: {
                    query: query,
                    fields: ['full_address']
                }
            },
            filter:{
                geo_distance:{
                    distance: "6miles",
                    location: "address.location" 
                }
            }
        }
    )
end
```

Mapping;

```
{ "addresses" : {
"mappings" : {
  "address" : {
    "properties" : {
      "county" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "full_address" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "location" : {
        "type" : "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: I am assuming `address.location` field is an array, so you might need to pass  it as `[lon , lat]`, reverse order. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#_lat_lon_as_array_3) on that, is that the case?

Comment: In my database location is saved as an string, and in the index it's a geo_point. Using either variation of [lon, lat] or [lat, lon] returns an 
undefined local variable or method error.

Comment: could you show us one sample location you have? how is it formatted?

Comment: {
  "_index" : "addresses",
  "_type" : "address",
  "_id" : "30",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"county":"","location":"53.476322,-2.231175","full_address":"London Road, Manchester, United Kingdom"}
}

Comment: latitude value ranges from -90 to +90 and longitude from -180 to +180, 269.99 is not valid and hence the error

Comment: When I manually enter them coordinates(lat/lon) to the location value, and do a search it returns expected results.

Comment: ok, that is weird, could you post the full trace from ES logs?

Comment: nested: QueryParsingException[illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194] for [geo_distance]];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"London Road, Manchester, United Kingdom","fields":["full_address"]}},"filter":{"geo_distance":{"distance":"6miles","location":"address.location"}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194] for [geo_distance]];

Comment: I have some geo data from [here](http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/spatial-search-tutorial.html), although I dont get an error 269.99999983236194 but get zero results, are you saying you manually entered "269.99999983236194" and got results? also what version of ES you are using?

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same error today but with longitude. Turns out Elasticsearch version 2.0 and newer only allows longitude values from range -180..180.

For example version 1.7.5 (which I had in my local environment) worked with both ranges -180..180 and 0..360.

Your error states:

> illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194]

For latitude, only values from range -90..90 are allowed.

The only fix is to re-compute lat/long values before sending them to Elasticsearch. For example for longitude you could do:

```
((longitude.to_f + 180) % 360) - 180
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to clean longitude with something like this:

```php
$adjustedLongitude = function($vongitude) {
    $result = $vongitude - 360 * floor($vongitude / 360);
    if (abs($result) > 180) {
        $result = 360 - $result;
    }

    return $result;
}
```